# MongoDB perform $reduce till a criteria is met

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

These are the intermediate results I have from running a $group on the original documents I have and using "$sum":1 to get their corresponding counts which i have stored in the attribute "value" as shown:

```
{
id: 1,
value: 10
},
{
id: 2,
value: 9
},
{
id: 3,
value: 8
},
{
id: 4,
value: 7
},
{
id: 5,
value: 6
}
```

In the first stage, I calculate the total of "value", and in the second stage I calculate the percentage of "value" wrt the total:

```
{
                "$group": {
                    "_id": 0,
                    "ids": { "$push": "$id" },
                    "values": { "$push": "$value" },
                    "totalSum": { "$sum": "$value" }
                }
            },
            {
                "$project": {
                    "ids": "$ids",
                    "values": "$values",
                    "totalSum": "$totalSum",
                    "percentages":
                        {
                            "$map": {
                                "input": "$values",
                                "as": "s",
                                "in": {
                                    "$multiply":
                                        [{ "$divide": ["$$s", "$totalSum"] }, 100]
                                }
                            }
                        }
                }
            }
```

Below is the result i get:

```
[ { _id: 0,
ids: [1,2,3,4,5],
values: [10,9,8,7,6],
totalSum: 40,
percentages: [25,22.5,20,17.5,15]}]
```

I want to add another stage in the pipeline where I am able to return a result whose cumulative/running percentage value reaches a threshold. eg. if the threshold is 50%, I want a result like this:

```
[{
ids: [1,2],
values: [10,9]
}]
```

Is it possible with reduce? Or any other pipeline?

Comment: It's usage is pretty much the same as any other higher order function elsewhere. Which means you basically have `$$value` for the output accumulator and `$$this` for **every** array item. So you can't "break the loop" as it were. Perhaps you could be more specific about what you actually want to do by including an example.

Comment: Hey, just edited the question. Hope it makes a little more sense. Going by your response though I don't think that's possible

Comment: I think you need to explain yourself a lot more clearly than that. Show us some sample data and what you expect to come out. It's not even clear why you even need ( or think you need ) `$reduce` here. It's pretty common that people think they need `$reduce` where something else actually already does the job.

Comment: Before you attempt to show us in the comment, use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49830107/edit) link on your question instead. Posting code in comments makes for horrible reading. Your question is where the body of what you are asking needs to be.

Comment: I wasn't going to post any code, but i've edited the question with an example. hope that offers enough clarity. Thanks!

Comment: Dude. You really should be posting your actual "documents in your collection" when asking questions here. You start writing psuedocode and trying to explain things ( not very well ) then everything just gets lost in the translation. For the sake of getting a **clear answer** ( without the back and forth of comments to clarify and correct ) then simply show some data in the format of "documents in a collection" as **input** and then show what the **output** is expected to be based on that.

Comment: Have a look Neil.

Comment: Why do these need to be in arrays? Why can you not simply do the math on each document and then `$match` in order to only show those "percentages" calcuated above your threshold? All I see here is "stuffing into arrays" for the sake of "stuffing into arrays". It's so much simpler when you just work with the documents. So either you're still not explaining something important, or your just missing the much clearer approach. Which is it?

Comment: :) I posted an intermediate document. Please understand I am following the right approach till the current point. I need help beyond this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168977/discussion-between-gmoksh-and-neil-lunn).

Comment: Let's not chat. How about you spend some time thinking about what I just said, and then if it actually needs more explanation then do so and ***thoroughly*** within the actual question you present. As I see the problem you have presented, it's simply solved by working with the documents and without the `$group` forcing all documents into a single one. If you still don't get the point then you probably are posting something "abstract" when you need to present your "real problem". Good luck. Post when you've made the changes, and if you need to.

Comment: Since u have enough time to write such a huge comment but not chat, I'd like you to know here that I have a lot of ids in my original documents and have grouped by those "ids" to get the corresponding "values" using "$sum":1. I posted the intermediate one because.. well it's obvious why i didn't post the original huge list of docs.